# Runtime of nested for loops

Tags: for-loop, runtime

```
for(i = 1; i < n*n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < i*i; j++){
        if(j % i == 0){
            for(k=0; k < j; k++){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt at a solution:

j iterates up to i*i = n^4.  For the 'k' loop, we have the sum of k from 1 to n^4 which is n^4(n^4-1)/2.  So the runtime is O(n^8).  This strikes me as too high, but I don't see an error.

Comment: The 2nd loop's increment is `i++` or `j++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop executes n<sup>2</sup> times. The next loop executes a total of ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup> i<sup>2</sup>, which is O(n<sup>6</sup>).

The innermost loop only runs when `j` is a multiple of `i`, which happens `i` times for each value of `i`. The innermost loop executes `j` times for each such value of `j`: `i`, `2i`, `3i`, and so forth until `i*i`. Thus, the innermost loop executes ∑<sub>j=1</sub><sup>i</sup> ij times, which is O(i<sup>3</sup>), for each `i`.

Therefore, the total running time is ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup> O(i<sup>3</sup>) + O(n<sup>6</sup>), which is O(n<sup>8</sup>) since ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup> O(i<sup>3</sup>) = O(n<sup>8</sup>).

(Note that I'm assuming the second loop increments `j++`, not `i++`. The answer is rather different if it's `i++`).

Comment: Yes the second loop increments j++, i've edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

So:

```
i goes from 1 to n*n.
j goes from 1 to i*i
```

But the inner most loop only runs when i divides j. There are exactly i numbers between 1 and i*i, which are divisible by i. Therefore the inner most loop will run i times for each i from 1 to n*n.

So far that's n^4.

But now j can be at most i*i, so at most n^4.

So yes, the complexity is O(n^8).